# Recursive Parser in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm writing a parser in Haskell, and one of the parsing functions (`prefixParser`) should return a modified version of itself on every call. The code here is simplified, but I hope every necessary bit of information is included.

```
type MyParsec r = Parsec [Char] () Identity r

newtype SomeResult = String

newtype RecursiveParser = MyParsec (SomeResult, RecursiveParser)

items :: RecursiveParser -> MyParsec [SomeResult]
items prefixParser = do
  (someResult, newPrefixParser) <- prefixParser
  rst <- items newPrefixParser
  return (someResult : rst)
```

Now the trouble is that `prefixParser`'s type is `RecursiveParser` but I call it inside a `do` block that expects a `MyParsec`. Ergo I get a

> Couldn't match expected type

error. Can I even do something like this or am I (as usual) not quite getting Haskell's type system?

(The `prefixParser` is meant to parse an incrementing number `[1. 2. 3. ...]`, and as of yet not implemented.)

Comment: use `type` instead of `newtype`

Comment: You are not using `newtype` correctly.  It's worth reading about `newtype` (and its big brother `data`)

Comment: @Li-yaoXia We can't use `type` recursively. He needs to use a `newtype`, but in the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
newtype RecursiveParser = MyParsec (SomeResult, RecursiveParser)
```

Above, `MyParsec` is the name of a new data constructor, which is completely unrelated to the `MyParser` type constructor. Essentially, the above definition defines `RecursiveParser` to be a pair `(SomeResult, RecursiveParser)`, wrapped under the new constructor `MyParsec`.

Recall the `newtype` syntax is

```
newtype NewtypeName = NewConstructorName SomeType
```

To actually use the `MyParsec (...)` type, you need to specify the name of the constructor as follows. It is customary to name it using the same name as the `newtype` itself.

```
newtype RecursiveParser = RecursiveParser (MyParsec (SomeResult, RecursiveParser))
```

Then, you can adapt your code so to remove the wrapper data constructor.

```
items :: RecursiveParser -> MyParsec [SomeResult]
items (RecursiveParser prefixParser) = do
  (someResult, newPrefixParser) <- prefixParser
  rst <- items newPrefixParser
  return (someResult : rst)
```

Comment: so it basically was a syntactical error on my part, oh my dear... thank you!